# SQL Get Row Count

Tags: php, sql

I have a `ticket` table:

`id`,`ref`,`email`,`type`,`org`

And a `people` table:

`id`,`tID`,`name`,`email`

`tID` is the `id` foreign key for table `ticket`.

Now, type is either 'single' or 'couple' or 'group'.  `org` is either 'RA', 'DUAL' or 'PIH'.

My problem is that I want to get some stats.  Now, I can do it the long way, by pulling all the data in PHP or, I'm sure, there is a quicker way to use SQL to get my row counts.

So for instance, I need total number of **people** that are 'single', for 'RA'.  How can I get that data?

Comment: I am sorry, I need people, not tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(p.tID)
from ticket as t inner join people as p 
on t.ID = p.tID
where t.type = 'single' and t.org = 'RA'
```

This query will help you count all the ticket that have `type = single` and `org = RA`

Comment: Sorry I meant to say **people** not tickets.

Comment: @Chud37 Answer edited, please take a look and tell me if it helps you or not

Comment: @Chud37 Answer edited, I tested it on mySQL and should get rid of the error

Comment: That works! Thank you! I always have problems with getting row counts.

Comment: @Chud37 You're welcome. You just need to figure out how to filter the result set the way you want, then add 'count' to your select statement

Answer (score 3):

> I need total number of tickets that are 'single', for 'RA'. How can I
>   get that data?

```
select  count(*)
from    ticket t
where   t.org = 'RA'
        and t.type = 'single'
```